# Python: I need to randomly generate 6 numbers who's sum adds up to a specified number

Tags: python, random

I am attempting to create a new character which has a randomly generated level. This character has 8 attributes, I need to randomly generate those 8 attributes so that their sum is equal to the generated level, plus 8.
So far I have this..

```
    level = random.randint(1, 30) * 5
    base = int(0.1 * level)
    stats = []

    *****

    health = int(atts[0])
    strength = int(atts[1])
    agility = int(atts[2])
    willpower = int(atts[3])
    charisma = int(atts[4])
    intelligence = int(atts[5])
    speed = int(atts[6])
    luck = int(atts[7])
```

I am looking to replace the asterisks with the code which would generate the 8 random integers that add up to the level + 8, and append them to "atts."
Based on other answers I have seen to similar questions, I tried the following which gets me the 8 integers I need, but I'm struggling with figuring out how to make them add up to the level.

```
    for i in range(0, 8):
       arr = random.randint(base, level)
       atts.append(arr)
```

Comment: So, allocate 7 random elements, and set the last to N+8 minus the sum of the rest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about you just pick a random attribute, increment it by one, and then repeat that `level + 8` times? Then you don't have to worry about generating numbers that satisfy your criteria:

```
from random import choice

level = 4
points = level + 8

attribute_names = (
    "health",
    "strength",
    "agility",
    "willpower",
    "charisma",
    "intelligence",
    "speed",
    "luck"
)

attributes = dict.fromkeys(attribute_names, 0)

for _ in range(points):
    key = choice(attribute_names)
    attributes[key] += 1

for key, value in attributes.items():
    print(f"{key}: {value}")
```

Output:

```
health: 2
strength: 0
agility: 3
willpower: 3
charisma: 2
intelligence: 0
speed: 0
luck: 2
```

Comment: This is the best way to avoid biasing the last element (i.e. using the "remainder" approach). OP probably needs to think about how these "random" values are supposed to be distributed.

Comment: This absolutely got me to where I needed to be, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_random_numbers_that_add_up_to(target=80, max_val=10, how_many=8):
    ints = []
    for i in range(how_many - 1):
        ints.append(
            random.randint(0, max_val)
        )
    sub_total = sum(ints)
    final_attribute = 40 - sub_total
    ints.append(final_attribute)
    return ints
```

This function will pick `how_many` random integers between 0 and `max_value`, and set the last to the diff between the sum of the existing ones and the `target` value.

You'll need to tune the args to make sure you don't go over `target`, otherwise the final attribute would be negative.